# Node.js - Pass context through to nested objects in function properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to make a cleanly name-spaced module in Node.js, break it up into sub-modules via `require()` and pass the root context/scope all the way to the methods in the name-spaces.

```
// index.js

  var SDK = function(data){
      this.data = data;
  };

  SDK.prototype.Utilities = require('./utilities');

  module.exports = function(data) {
      return new SDK(data);
  };

// utilities.js

  module.exports = {
       callAPI: function() {
            console.log(this.data);
       }  
  };   


// Use-case (somewhere in the node.js app...)

  var SDK = require('./index')("this is some data");
  SDK.Utilities.callAPI();  
  // Should return "this is some data"
```

For example:

`this` in `SDK` needs to be accessible in `SDK.Utilities.callAPI();`, like below.  `Utilities` is the name-space I'm referring to.

I'm aware of javascript `bind()` and `call()` techniques, but I'm not sure how to use them in this particular case.

Comment: OK - one last thing, could you add an example of how you want to be able to use it? Pseudocode is fine

Comment: Yes.  I've just added the use-case to the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **apply** or **call**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

these run the function with the given **this** scope.

Comment: I'm aware of this.  But I don't know how to do this while dividing up the module into submodules via `require()`.  Could you please provide a written example of how this would work in my specific case?